# I have multiple animated creatures/objects in my filter, but only one is actually animating

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Each creature/object is animated with its own keyframes in Blender and appears to be working in that software. But when we export over into Spark AR, only one creature/object appears to animate, the rest stay still.

I tried to export the file normally, and expected each creature/object to move like they do in Blender. However, each stays in its first frame position, except for the first, which animates properly.

Comment: Have you tried importing one object at a time? It might not be able to handle a full project full of animated objects at once, so it might be worth going through to delete the other objects. Never used Spark AR so this is just a guess. You could also try maybe parenting all of the objects to an empty object then exporting the empty object?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add fbx's to the project with multiple animated models, we had to set some pretty significant and not necessarily intuitive flags during the export process.

Need to set the "NLA Strips" and "All Actions" to FALSE when exporting a file with multiple objects that are animated.

See Also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142783/can-i-export-multiple-objects-with-individual-animations-to-fbx